# The order of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am understanding a proof

**Theorem**:

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. If $p\equiv3\bmod{4}$, then one of the congruences $x^2\equiv2\bmod{p}$ or $x^2\equiv-2\bmod{p}$ is solvable.

**Sketch of Proof**:

> Let $G=\Bbb F_p^\times$ be the multiplicative group of nonzero elements in $\Bbb F_p$, so that $|G|=p-1=2m$ for some odd $m$. The subset $H$ of all elements of odd order is a subgroup of order m and index 2. Since $[-1]\neq H$, $G=H\cup -H$. It can be shown that one of 2 and -2 lies in $H$. Since every element in a finite abelian group of odd order has a unique square root, the proof is done.

What I cannot understand is why $H$ has order m? I really cannot figure it out, but I think it should be obvious. Any help?

(This proof is from Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra 2nd, Lemma 2.88)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $G=\Bbb F_p^\times$ is a *cyclic* group, say generated by $g$. What is the order of $g^2$?

Comment: Since $g$ has order $p-1$ and $p-1=2m$, $g^2$ has order $m$. For every $h\in\langle g^2\rangle$, the order of $h$ divides $m$; hence, the order of $h$ must be odd. That means $\langle g^2\rangle\subset H$. If $g^k\in H$ has order $l$, then $2m|(kl)$, so that $2|k$ or $2|l$. But, $l$ is odd, so $2|k$, and $g^k\in\langle g^2\rangle$. Therefore, $\langle g^2\rangle=H$. Am I right?

Comment: If I were your professor I would give you an A+! Well done!

Comment: Thank you! I just need a little hint, and yours is just exactly what I need. ;)

Comment: @Y.Fan - maybe good to know - in general, if $G$ is a finite group of order $|G|=2m$, with $m$ *odd*, then $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of order $m$. Of course this subgroup equals the subset of all elements of odd order. Even a more general result is true, but that requires more group theoretic knowledge.